# servlet reults in page not found error and wrong mapping to the endpoint specified in the annotation

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

i am learning how to create servlets. i followed this tutorial

```
https://medium.com/@prashant.srivastava7744/how-to-create-hello-world-servlet-example-using-eclipse-ide-with-tomcat-7-39fdbdc21573
```

it shows how to create simple hello world servlet.
i followed the steps mentioned in the tutorial but when i run the code via
right click
run as
run on server

i receive

```
HTTP Status 404 – nicht gefunden"page not found"
```

and i noticed that despite the end point which stated in the annotation is

```
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
```

it gets change to be

```
http://localhost:8080/ServletHelloWorld/
```

it should be

```
http://localhost:8080/tHelloWorld/
```

please let me know how to fix this error

**code**:

```
        package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorld
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public HelloWorld() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("Hello World!");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
    }

}
```

**folder structure**:

[image]

**web.xml**:
[image]

Comment: Have you check with this URL: http://localhost:8080/ServletHelloWorld

Comment: @mcacorner please read my question again